# How can I get the ActiveRecord class for which an ActiveRecord::Relation instance was created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Imagine an `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass called `Podcast`.

If I have an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance created from that class:

```
podcasts = Podcast.where(...)
```

Is there a way to infer the class from which the `podcasts` relation was created **without executing the query**?

Comment: what does `podcasts.methods` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call `model` on the relation:

```
Podcast.where(...).model #=> Podcast
```